# None data in msg.send django

Tags: python, django

One more question about Django

Sending email by using **EmailMultiAlternatives** sends messages but data is 'None'

My **views.py** looks like:

```
def sendmail_ru(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    subject = request.POST.get('subject')
    args['subject'] = subject
    message = request.POST.get('message')
    args['message'] = str(name) + str(email) + "<p>" + str(name) + "</p>"
    subject, from_email, to = subject, 'info@example.com', 'reciever@example.com'
    text_content = 'This is an important message.'
    html_content = args['message']
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send(args)
    return render_to_response('mail-success-ru.html', args)
```

After cending email, reciever recives it's message but all data is 'None'

**Example**

```
Subject: None
-------------

Message: NoneNone None
----------------------
```

Comment: Is there actually anything in the POST variables subject and message?

Comment: Try `msg.send(**args)`

Comment: TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'csrf_token'

Comment: Why do you add `csrf_token` to the args dict?

Comment: Selcuk, yes there is, if I use the sameview (w/o msg.send) and render somepage.html template which contains {{ message }} then  it gives me exactly what I need

Comment: because I use form with {% csrf_token %}

Comment: And why are you passing `args` to `send` at all?

Comment: ilse, i don't know... I've found this code in one tutorial, and I thought that if I use args dictionary, then I should use args in send

Answer (score -1):

I've found my problem

The problem was not in csrf or args

The problem was in

I used inputs Id="name"
But in fact, I should use name="name" or name="subject" in forminputs